# Is it possible to preserve whitespace?

Tags: javaparser

Using the [javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) library:

Is there a way to print out a compilation unit and preserve whitespace?

I tried the toString() method on compilationUnit but that throws away newlines.

Seeing as how each ASTNode stores line and column number information, am I just missing the proper method?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. A quote [from the dev](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/issues/detail?id=9&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Stars%20Summary):

> The DumpVisitor needs to be rewrite because it don't respects the
>   token positions, when it has been done will be more easy to treat comments into the
>   dumper.

Unfortunately this project seems pretty dead anyway: the last activity was circa 2008.